# phpexcel not writing data to excel file using setCellValueByColumnAndRow

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("untitled.xls");

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) //loop through the 3 worksheets of KindleEditionEISBN
{
$sheet_name = $worksheet->getTitle();  

if ($worksheet->getTitle = 'Records')
{
$highestColumm = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestColumn();
$highestRow = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($highestColumm, $highestRow, $node_10); 
$objWriter2007 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter2007->save('php://output');
```

The above is my code, I run it and the if loop works because I am getting the output but it does not do anything in my "untitled.xls" file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code won't write anything to `untitled.xls` because you're saving to `php://output` (the screen) so the content of the file should be displayed on screen unless you're also sending headers to tell a browser to treat the output as an Excel file; and you're using the Excel2007 Writer to generate the output as an OfficeOpenXML format xlsx file rather than as a BIFF format xls file.

So are you seeing the output on screen?

Comment: thanks mark! had an bunch of phpexcel questions and you always the man with the info!